# Appirater alert doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, appirater

When in debug mode, the alert shows up every time - it works fine!
No alert shows up when:

```
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];     
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:0];     
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2]; 
[Appirater setDebug:NO];
...
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to remove the application from your simulator / device ? If, for instance, at one point you selected « No, Thanks » to dismiss the RatingView, it would still show up when using `[Appirater setDebug:YES]` but would not otherwise. Reinstall the application to remove any saved key in `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=XXXXXXX"; //your app id.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```